# Azure Webjobs SDK is deleting a message when there is a binding failure - Bug?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-webjobs

ASP.NET Webjobs is incorrectly deleting a message in a queue when there is a binding failure.
The correct process should be that the message is not deleted and reappears after the visibility timeout to be processed again.

Here is the invocation log

```
    running in pid: 6424
Timestamp:10:02:27 PM
Parameters bound. Invoking user function.
--------
--------
Exception while executing:
System.InvalidOperationException, Error while binding function parameters.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.RunnerProgram.InvokeWorker(MethodInfo m, BindResult[] binds, ParameterInfo[] ps)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.RunnerProgram.Invoke(IConfiguration config, MethodInfo m, FunctionInstanceGuid instance, IRuntimeBindingInputs inputs, ParameterRuntimeBinding[] argDescriptors)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.RunnerProgram.Invoke(FunctionInvokeRequest invoke, IConfiguration config)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Jobs.RunnerProgram.MainWorker(FunctionInvokeRequest descr, IConfiguration config)

FAIL
```

Has anyone else come across messages being incorrectly dequeued (deleted) when using Webjobs SDK?

The binding failure is due to invalid JSON format in the input, but I think that unless there is a proper exit to the invocation I don't think the input message should be deleted.

This is the method signature in the webjobs console app

```
public static void CreateCertificate(
        [QueueInput  ("certificaterequest")    ]      CertificateRequest inputcertificate,
        [QueueOutput ("certificatemade")       ]  out CertificateRequest outputcertificate,
        [BlobOutput  ("certificatemade/{Guid}")]      TextWriter writer)
    {
```

Comment: The message is removed from the queue for 10 minutes, if the method fails it should return to the queue (after 10 minutes) are you sure it didn't?

Comment: @John,  I'm looking into this issue and I will update soon with the results.

Comment: Yeah I am sure that it didn't return to the queue.

Comment: I have also done some performance tests on this with 200 byte JSON payloads, and its taking 400ms per operation/invocation. Is this a Nagle related issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug. I've logged it and we are going to do more investigation.

Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: Hi, was this bug fixed? Also any idea about @John's comment on the time taken? I'm waiting for webjobs to exit preview, they seem really useful (especially queue input binding)